# Question on Email Replies for Email to Case

Tags: email2case

I am hoping someone can help with this. I have email to case set up with the thread id in the subject and description.

The issue I run into is that when a customer sends in an email cc'ed one of their colleagues. If the colleague who is cc'ed responds to the email, it creates a new case instead of appending to the existing case.

I know this is because there is no thread id to tie it back to, but is there a way to group it based on a different method? Right now, we are using the merge feature to group the conversations together, but it is rather inconvenient for our team to continue doing this.

Comment: Is there any reason the colleague can't just be added in the To Address to avoid this mess if they might respond?

Comment: That is a behavior we aren't able to control for unfortunately since the customer would have to add the colleague in the To address field.